# How do you know which pin corresponds Hall sensor 1, 2, and 3 so that I can pair it with the correct phase wire in a BLDC motor?

Tags: sensor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I recently bought a brushless sensored DC motor on Amazon which you can [find here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PNMYHFT).

I didn't really know what I was doing at the time when I bought this motor, but now I'm realizing it might have been a mistake because there is no data sheet that comes with it (at least I couldn't find one.)

I can't seem to figure out what all the pins coming out mean. There are 8 pins total coming out of my motor.

There are 3 bigger wires coming out which are for the 3 phases, and a 5 pin connector. I'm assuming the 5 pin connector is for the 5 volt power supply, ground connection, and the other 3 are for the 3 Hall effect sensors. First of all is that correct? If so how, do I figure out which of the 5 pin connector corresponds to 5 volts, ground, and the sensors? More specifically which sensor corresponds to which phase wire so I can hook it up phase 1 to sensor 1, phase 2 to sensor 2, phase 3 to sensor 3?

Comment: Always works out cheaper to buy a more expensive motor that comes with a data sheet.

Comment: Yeah.... I screwed up haha. This is the first project i've ever done so i'm learning.

Comment: @Trev347 Others there seem to have figured it out. *"They do come with 5 wire sensor cable. Not a problem, just wire into your 6 wire harness and skip the temperature pin."* Have you tried just asking on Amazon? (I have zero experience with these boards, motors, and controllers. So without having one here in my hands, I probably can't help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best indicator that I found to know the pin out configuration is to look at the colors of the wire and make your best guess.

For example my motor had a 6 pin out configuration. The red wire was obviously 5V pin, the hall sensor 1, hall sensor 2, and hall sensor 3 wires corresponded to the same color as the 3 phase wires coming out of the motor. This left me with a black and white wire for the ground and temperature pin. At first I wasn't really sure which one was which so I just took a guess and checked if it worked. By testing this I figured out black corresponded to GND and white corresponded to TEMP pin configuration. This was the case for my motor, but you would need to test the motor yourself to be sure.

** Side Note **

I had to use a PULLUP resistor on all of my hall sensor pins in order to get a reading.

**How do you know which hall sensors correspond with which phase?**

The best way I found to do this was by simply putting current through the first phase wire and having current come back out the second phase wire and rotating the motor by hand. By doing this you can feel when the motor has the strongest magnetic pull and you can use `Serial.println(hallSensor1 / hallSensor2 / hallSensor3)`to determine which pin corresponds to the correct phase wires. Then repeat for the other 5 phases. I found that for [my motor which is a 6374 motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L5WDTSZ) about .5 Amps worked good enough for me to feel the magnetic force.

Answer (score 0):

Colors should help you.
Red -> 5V. Black -> Gnd.

[link example1](https://www.haydonkerkpittman.com/-/media/ametekhaydonkerk/images/white-papers/connecting-brushless-dc-motors-to-electronic-controllers/figure_1.jpg?revision=f42d675f-a2b8-4595-bed1-bb346acf9d9c&la=en&hash=B218C5568753B22608151E04ED9DD172)  [link example2](https://www.electronicshub.org/brushless-dc-motor-bldc-motor/)

[image]

[image]

Rotating the motor by hand should give the Hall sequence (A, B, C).
Testing with low voltages helps identify the corresponding others (power).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
But I found that this 5-pin connector is standard, so it always has the same pinout.

Note: This is a 6-pin connector that has a temperature sensor.
For your motor, just ignore the TMP pin.

[image: female connector that connects to your motor connector]

Image link :
https://flipsky.net/collections/electronic-products/products/flipsky-dual-mini-fsesc6-7-pro-140a-base-on-vesc6-6-with-aluminum-anodized-heat-sink

Comment: My motor was very similar to this one, but it had H1, H2, H3 below the TMP pin. So it went starting from the bottom and moving to the top - 5V, H1, H2, H3, TMP, GND. So make sure you double check. Color of the wires is probably the best indicator.